# Jquery thumbnail gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jquery thumbnail gallery like this one (or similar) on http://www.badoo.com .
Anyone know where can I get it?
Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this posting for creating a collage, which I believe is similar to what you want:

> http://superdit.com/2010/12/28/create-collage-image-gallery-with-jquery/

You will probably have to kick the source around a bit to do precisely what you want, bit it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin which helps you to create a collage - https://github.com/sandeepravi/collage.

With a little bit HTML/CSS and this plugin, you can easily create the collage.

Hope this helps!